# Update поля в документе MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Выполняю урок по видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el24xavOeWs , на 1:26 такой код обновления поля `name`:

```
app.put('/artists/:id', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('artists').updateOne(
        { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) },
        { name: req.body.name },
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    );
});
```

Код не сработал. Почитав документацию по MongoDB изменил код следующим образом:

```
app.put('/artists/:id', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('artists').update(
        { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) },
        { $set: { name: req.body.name } },
        {
            upsert: false,
            multi: false
        },
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    );
});
```

Когда через дополнение браузера RESTED отправляю непустой запрос `PUT` на любой существующий адрес, например, `http://localhost:3012/artists/5ab0e28867723c66e0c50afc`, то значение `name` документа с ObjectID `5ab0e28867723c66e0c50afc` становится равным `null`, хотя я отправляю непустую строку. Код ответа при этом - `200`. Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы он заработал и поле нормально обновлялось?

P.S. Когда перед в предыдущем уроке через RESTED работал с массивом, а не с БД, обновлялось всё нормально, т.е. ошибка не в том, что я не могу нормально послать запрос через RESTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывел `console.log(req.body.name);`, он оказался пустым, как и `console.log(req.body);`. Добавил ещё 2 параметра в JSON запрос в RESTED, все 3 параметра, включая `name`, нормально пришли и отобразились в `console.log(req.body);`. После этого всё нормально приходило из RESTED и без замечаний заносилось в БД. Ошибка была в работе RESTED.